# Can I get public data of other users using new Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an app, which has such flow:

1. User types in his/her username (only)
2. I get user's newest photos, and he/she is able to select some of them
3. Then I get the data of the photos he/she selected (likes, location, etc.)
4. Show them gallery of selected photos with their data.

My first question is: Can this be accomplished at all with new API?

[This page of documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/) says that I need this permission:

> **public_content** - to read any public profile info and media *on a user’s behalf*

Does this mean, if I get this permission, I'll be able, to fetch user's data only using his/her username? (If I'm authorized as My App's instagram user)

Comment: **My own answer:**
Yes, you can, using `public_content` permission, get other user's data. But you need to authenticate and I couldn't find a way to automatize it.